# How can I deploy a single package from SQL Server Data Tools in SSIS 2012?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I've got a number of SSIS packages spread across multiple projects in SQL Server Data Tools (formerly BIDS), which I want to deploy to the SSIS Catalog DB on my server.

When I want to deploy an entire project, I can just right-click the project and hit Deploy, to start the SSIS deployment wizard.  However, there doesn't seem to be an option to do this for a single package only, without redeploying the rest of the packages in the same project.

Does anyone know if it's possible to deploy just a single package using the deployment wizard, independently from the others in the project?

Comment: Are you using the package deployment model (legacy) or project deployment model (new)?

Comment: Project Deployment model I believe (I have a menu option to "convert to Package Deployment model").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible via the deployment wizard or SSDT.  Similar discussion in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/sqlintegrationservices/thread/da414fc4-5f17-4378-b408-450d4d18038e)...where the original poster proposes a (terribly manual) workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to get [BIDSHelper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Deploy%20SSIS%20Packages) from Codeplex (free tool).  It contains a utility to allow you to deploy SSIS packages from BIDS.  I haven't tested BIDS Helper with SSDT yet.  Also you might want to grab [SSIS Package Manager](http://pacman.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex as well.

Comment: From the looks of it, these tools only seem to work with the older SSIS package store and not the new 2012 SSIS Catalogue DB.  Both seem like decent tools for use with <2012 systems though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server Management Studio to import a single package:

1. In SSMS, connect to your Integration Services instance.
2. Right-click the appropriate node (File System or MSDB) and select **Import Package**.
3. Set Package Location to **File System**.
4. Click the three dots next to Package Path. Browse to your SSDT project and select the .dtsx file you want to import.
5. Click OK. If prompted to overwrite the existing package, click Yes.

Comment: This will deploy only selected package(s) and Remove the other ones from SSIS Catalog.